# Java 8 Unsigned Integer Addition and Potential Overflow

Tags: numbers, java-8, addition, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I'm working exercises from the book "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann. One of the exercises based on the improvements in the `Number` classes asks:

> Write a program that adds, subtracts, divides, and compares numbers
>   between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, using `int` values and unsigned
>   operations. Show why `divideUnsigned` and `remainderUnsigned` are
>   necessary.

The problem is, if you add 2 unsigned ints, the sum may overflow the integer limit. I don't see a way to prevent that without using a long to store the sum and checking if it's greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Is it possible to do this using ints only?

Answer (score 6):

The [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) used for integer values has the neat property that for adding and subtracting it is irrelevant whether you interpret the values as signed or unsigned.

Therefore, even at CPU level, there are no distinct instructions for adding/subtracting signed or unsigned numbers. It’s all about interpretation.

So when you add or subtract two unsigned numbers using the signed `int` type, the result may overflow in the signed `int` range. But when printing the now-negative number using [`Integer.toUnsignedString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-) the result will be the correct unsigned value, assuming that the operation didn’t even overflow in the unsigned integer value range.

That’s why the class [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) provides special unsigned operations only where necessary, i.e. for comparing two unsigned values, for division and remainder and for conversions from and to `String` (and to `long`, while a type-cast from `long` to `int` is already sufficient for the other direction).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure if the question is with printing only. If the overflow value is returned and to be used in some other operation, it's going to be incorrect. The "exact" operations that have been introduced in Java 8, [intValueExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValueExact--) throw exceptions in such cases.

Comment: Since the exercise mandates the use of `int` for calculations, there is no way around it. Of course, you may define the API of your calculation in a safe way, i.e. you can use [`Integer.toUnsignedLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedLong-int-) to return the value (which you calculated using `int`) in a form which can’t be misinterpreted. Of course, the same would hold if you returned the result as `String` using [`toUnsignedString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-) “calculation” `!=` “return type”

Comment: I was hoping that there's more to it than that. If you read the question, it says "using `int` values and unsigned operations". If seems beyond trivial to create a method that uses the `+` operator to add 2 ints. The exercise doesn't add any value unless we're missing something.

Comment: Maybe you should focus on the last sentence of your exercise: “Show why [`divideUnsigned`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#divideUnsigned-int-int-) and [`remainderUnsigned`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#remainderUnsigned-int-int-) are necessary”. This implies that you should dig deep enough into the 2’s Complement *to understand* why it works for `+`, `-`, and `*` but not for `/` and `%` so you will understand the API design decision made for Java 8 to add these two support methods but no `addUnsigned`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain an unsigned int, you need to use the `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` functions or do a manual calculation. Remember, Java doesn't actually HAVE unsigned integers, Java8 just provides the ability to treat an int as unsigned in order to allow for a greater range of positive-number values.

According to the [Java 8 Doc for the Integer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-),

> An unsigned integer maps the values usually associated with negative
>   numbers to positive numbers larger than MAX_VALUE

So the conversion between an unsigned int and a signed one is that if the number is greater than or equal to zero AND less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it remains the same. If it's greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE but still within the unsigned range, then to store it in an `int`, you need to add 2^31 to it, which will convert it to the correct value due to the way that addition overflow is defined as an operation. Overflow and underflow in addition of binary primitives like `int` just causes the counter to reset and continue counting.

```
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;            // -2147483648
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;            // 2147483647
int overByOne = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;  // -2147483648 : same as Integer.MIN_VALUE
int underByOne = Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1; // 2147483647 : same as Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

They exercise is just asking you to look at the Integer class and test out the various (new in Java8) methods for unsigned operations. Java does not have unsigned integer primitives, but an int value can be treated as unsigned for the purposes of certain new methods in the Integer class.